# Does anyone know a good way to preview website psds on desktop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, interface-design

Does anyone know of a good live desktop preview tool for when you're designing websites? I've noticed when I'm designing websites, the elements can come out a bit too large since in Photoshop, I'm a little bit zoomed out when I work.

Something like Adobe Preview CC would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't zoom out so much? ...or zoom to 100% to preview it?

Comment: You don’t know the level of zoom the user’s browser will have either.

Answer (score 1):

[XnView MP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) is a powerful cross-platform media browser, viewer and converter that is compatible with more than 500 formats, including Adobe Photoshop psd. XnView MP is free for private and educational use, but if you intend to use XnView in a company, you must purchase a license.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop already provides a live preview. You can make a second window by choosing Window ➔ Arrange ➔ New Window and set the second window to whatever zoom level and size that you want to simulate a browser, and/or place the second window on another display.